# Transform \sepfootnotecontent into an environment

Tags: macros, environments, footnotes

I am currently cleaning the code of a 1000-page book that contain *hundreds* of *very long* footnotes so I decided to move them into separate files using the sepfootnotes package. It’s easy to use:

```
\sepfootnotecontent{label}{The content}
...
\sepfootnote{label}
```

As I said, the footnotes are very long and the footnote file is hard to read. Using an environment would make it easier to parse:

```
\begin{nbp}{label}
The content
\end{nbp}
```

(“nbp” stands for “note de bas de page”, it’s a french document.)

I found out that the environ package makes it easy to “turn” a command into an environment:

```
\NewEnviron{nbp}[1]{\sepfootnotecontent{#1}{\BODY}}
```

There is no error during the compilation but nothing appears in the footnote:

```
\begin{nbp}{1}
dolor sit amet.
\end{nbp}
Lorem ipsum\sepfootnote{1}
```

[image: Disapearing footnote content]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}

\NewEnviron{nbp}[1]{\sepfootnotecontent{#1}{\BODY}}

\begin{document}
\sepfootnotecontent{works}{dolor sit amet.}
\begin{nbp}{doesntwork}
dolor sit amet.
\end{nbp}
Lorem ipsum\sepfootnote{works}\sepfootnote{doesntwork}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would be nice if there were a *complete* [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) to work with....

Comment: @jon Here is the MWE, after fighting with the `minimal` class that don’t recognize `\sepfootnote` :(

Comment: Oh yeah: don't use the `minimal` class for minimal examples.  (Confusing, I realize, but that is not what it was designed for.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to change the internals of `sepfootnotes`: an `\aftergroup` trickery is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}

\NewEnviron{nbp}[1]{%
  \xdef\nbptemp{{#1}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}}%
  \aftergroup\donpb
}
\newcommand{\donpb}{\expandafter\sepfootnotecontent\nbptemp}

\begin{document}
\sepfootnotecontent{works}{Dolor sit amet.}
\begin{nbp}{doesntwork}
Again dolor sit amet.
\end{nbp}
Lorem ipsum\sepfootnote{works}\sepfootnote{doesntwork}
\end{document}
```

<sub>Note: I compiled the file with a reduced `\textheight` just to have a smaller image.</sub>

[image]

Comment: Your answer is better because it doesn’t any extra packages. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems: the marco `\sepfootnotecontent` saves its contents locally which means it is forgotten after the environment ends. The second problem: the macro `\BODY` is saved as footnote content but what you really want is it the first expansion of `\BODY` and not the macro itself.

With the help of the `etoolbox` package and its `\patchcmd` we can easily create a global version of the internal macro `\sep@namedef`:

```
\let\sep@namegdef\sep@namedef
\patchcmd\sep@namegdef{\@namedef}{\global\@namedef}{}{}
```

Now we need a global equivalent of `\sepfootnotecontent`:

```
% \gsepfootnoteenvcontent{<content>}{<id>}
\newcommand\gsepfootnoteenvcontent[2]{\sep@namegdef{sepfoot}{#2}{#1}}
```

Note the swap of the last two arguments: this makes it easier to expand the `\BODY` macro in the next step before passing it to `\sep@namegdef`.

Last the environment where `\BODY` is expanded before it is passed to `\gsepfootnoteenvcontent`:

```
\NewEnviron{nbp}[1]{\expandafter\gsepfootnoteenvcontent\expandafter{\BODY}{#1}}
```

A full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,etoolbox}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}

\makeatletter
% \gsepfootnoteenvcontent{<content>}{<id>}
\newcommand\gsepfootnoteenvcontent[2]{\sep@namegdef{sepfoot}{#2}{#1}}
\let\sep@namegdef\sep@namedef
\patchcmd\sep@namegdef{\@namedef}{\global\@namedef}{}{}
\makeatother

\NewEnviron{nbp}[1]{\expandafter\gsepfootnoteenvcontent\expandafter{\BODY}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\sepfootnotecontent{works}{dolor sit amet.}
\begin{nbp}{doesntwork}
dolor sit amet.
\end{nbp}

Lorem ipsum\sepfootnote{works}\sepfootnote{doesntwork}

\end{document}
```